# EJS include: Render data from controller?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Inside my index.ejs (standard html file):

```
<% include taskList %>
```

My taskList.ejs tries to access a variable (tasks) which is delivered from the controller:

```
exports.taskList = function(req, res) {
    res.render('taskList', {
        tasks: tasks
    });
}
```

This doesn't seem to be possible when including the taskList as the include doesn't call the controller -> tasks is undefined.
Any solution to this?

Comment: probably change `include taskList` to `include tasks`? also you are attempting to render `taskList.ejs` not `index.ejs`

Comment: But I want to render taskList (inside my index).